# Sphinx search query - condition for numbers in varchar column

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, sphinx

I have items and list in which categories exists:

```
id | name       | categories(varchar)
1  | bike red   | 2,5,18
2  | bike black | 4,7,13
```

With Sphinx I need to serach for example: **bike** AND only from category **5**

Is any good way how search in column categories?

In MySql I could write: WHERE name LIKE '%bike%' AND categories LIKE '%5%'

But my Sphinx index is big and searching could be not efective. Is any way like create integer ENUM list or? What could be good solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sphinx has Multi-Value Attributes http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#mva . pretty much perfect for this!

It works kinda like a numeric `set` in MySQL! (you have multiple categories, so `set`, not `enum`)

It will even automatically parse a string list of numbers seperated by commas during indexing.

```
sql_query = SELECT id,name,categories FROM item
sql_attr_multi = uint categories from field;
```

Then a sphinxQL query...

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE MATCH('bike') AND categories=5
```

(This may look confusing if familar with MySQL. an equality filter on a MVA attribute, actully just means *equals one of the values*. If want could write `categories IN (5)` - same effect)